# Why doesn't this regex work?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I want to look at the output of `git status -s` to determine whether there are any untracked files in the tree. I tried the following test, but the regex doesn't match. Why not?

```
$ git status -s
## master
 M updated-file
?? new-file
$ [[ $(git status -s) =~ ^\?\? ]] || echo "no match"
no match
```

I'd also like to be able to test for added/modified/deleted files in the same way. I'd normally just use something like `^\s*[AMD]` for this purpose, but this doesn't work either. What gives?

Comment: The output starts with `#`, not `??`. The match is against the whole string, not each line in the string. You probably want to match against `$'\n'??`. What not use `grep` though? `git status -s | grep -q '^??' || echo no match`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're matching against the whole string, not each line of the string, as such you're really testing against `##` in that regex.

`grep` is a better choice for this:

```
if ! git status -s | grep -q '^??'; then
    echo "no match"
fi
```

As requested, you can do the same for added/modified/deleted:

```
git status -s | grep '^ *[AMD]'
```

You might also want to look into `git status --porcelain` (an option that first appeared in 1.7.0), which is more oriented towards parsing.

Comment: Thanks – that was a rather obvious mistake! I'm using `grep` now as suggested, and I'll look into `--porcelain`.